# Get-ADUser -Properties not returning PasswordNeverExpires for all users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords, user-accounts

I am trying to list all users that have the `PasswordNeverExpires` flag set.

If I use

```
Get-ADUser
```

I get a list of all users in my domain, along with a load of default properties.

If I use

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name | Format-Table -Property Name -AutoSize
```

I also get a list of all usernames in my domain, as a table.

When I use

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,PasswordNeverExpires | Format-Table -Property Name,PasswordNeverExpire
```

I get a table that contains a full list of usernames, but ONLY the following accounts have either `True` or `False` in the `PasswordNeverExpires` column

```
Guest
krbtgt
Administrator
SBSMonAcct
Network Administrator
<MyDomainAdminAccount>
SPSearch
<AnAdministratorAccountForOneOfOurSoftwareVendors>
<AnAccountThatWasCopiedFromTheDomainAdministratorAccount>
<AnotherAccountCopiedFromTheDomainAdministratorAccount>
```

All the other items/usernames in the table have empty/blank/non-existent values.

I have also tried

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))"
```

but that only returns

```
<MyDomainAdminAccount>
SPSearch
```

Why is the `PasswordNeverExpires` flag not being picked up for all users? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PasswordNeverExpires` is calculated from the `userAccountControl` attribute.

Probably the fastest way to search for users that have that flag set is as follows:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)" -Properties PasswordNeverExpires
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax) for more information on searching using a bitwise filter. 65536 (0x10000) corresponds to the `ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD` bit position, so this LDAP search filter searches only for accounts that have that flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your third line pulls the property "PasswordNeverExpires" but Selects "PasswordNeverExpire".  If this was just a typo in your question this disregard.  If not then there is your answer.  :-)